# Facebook Developer Policy 6.1: Verify that you have integrated Login correctly. Your app shouldn't crash or hang during the testing process

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, policy

I'm using FB login in my app, the login works fine.But today I received an email from Facebook team. They're told me that our Android app is being affected. But I checked my crashlytics and also test on my live app. I could't find an issues. So, how I can solve this issue?

Hi,

In order to keep the Meta platform and community safe, we periodically review apps for compliance. We need the following information/action from you on your app,(AppId:XXXX), in order to approve your app’s continued operation on our platform.

***Platforms affected: Android.***

**Developer Policy 6.1: Verify that you have integrated Login correctly. Your app shouldn't crash or hang during the testing process.**

During Login, your app is crashing or hanging excessively, creating a broken experience for people trying to use your app. To make sure this flow runs smoothly, check that you've integrated Facebook Login correctly. We recommend that you test Login on all integrations.

Comment: *your app is crashing or hanging excessively* It may be not crashing but may be hanging. Try to test your application on all set of android version and phone models.

Comment: Have you found out anything more about what the problem is in your case?

Comment: @Oli Yes, I found this problem and I solved this. I have used older facebook library then I updated my facebook dependencies. You can be follow this link: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/06/28/deprecating-support-fb-login-authentication-android-embedded-browsers/

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?